# Getting an error unexpected alert open when get alert confirmation popup

Tags: node.js

I want to click on OK button in the alert confirmation popup but I'm getting the following error:

> "unexpected alert open" when confirmation popup alert is shown

Used browser accept Alert and that does not work

Comment: Using webdriverio and javascript

Comment: An addition like the comment mentioning additional technologies should be made in an [edit] to the question. While you are doing that please add a [mcve].

Comment: Syntax Highlighting

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by removing screenshot capture right after the popup Alert.

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feXHC.png)